# Locus traced in complex plane

Tags: complex-numbers

If $z$ is a complex number satisfying the equation $|z-(1+i)|^2 =2$ and $m=\frac{2}{z}$ ,then what is the locus traced by $m$ in the complex plane .

I know $z$ is a locus of circle with centre $(1,1)$ and radius $\sqrt 2$.

But not getting any idea to solve for $m$

---

The answer is given as $x-y-1=0$

Comment: Inversions in circles should be useful, because the map $f(z)=2/z$ is an inversion in the circle of radius $\sqrt{2}$ centered on the origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $z=\frac 2m$ and substitute this into the locus given so you have $$\left|\frac{2-(1+i)m}{m}\right|^2=2$$
So $$|2-(m(1+i)|^2=2|m|^2$$

Now write $m=x+iy$ and do some simplification, and you will end up with $y=x-1$ as desired.

Shall I leave this to you?